# Scala parse currency amount and remove the currency sign

Tags: regex, scala

I have currency string that i want to convert into `Double` value:

```
val num = "181.13 kr"
val parsed = num.replaceAll("\\p{Sc}|,", "")

parsed = 181.13 kr
```

This example not working but in this case this works fine:

```
val num = "€11.22"
val parsed = num.replaceAll("\\p{Sc}|,", "")

parsed = 11.22
```

Comment: Do not use `Double` or `Float` for currency...

Comment: Why not ? i want to calculate several values

Comment: Josh Bloch explains the problem better than I could in item 48 of Effective Java.

Comment: OK i will read it, but what about my problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the question, whether to use `Double` or `Float` for currency: `\p{Sc}` doesn't match `kr` because it's not a currency symbol. Add `\p{L}` to match any letters ("€" could be "EUR" in some case).

```
val parsed = num.replaceAll("\\p{Sc}|\\p{L}|,", "")
```

Comment: It's more effecient to use a character class. Also, I think, you also need to filter space characters as well, to be able to convert the resulting number to a `BigDecimal` straightaway. Thus the regex is: `[\\p{Sc}\\p{L}\\p{Zs},]`